# What does 'left' field of strace select mean?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, select-syscall

I'm using strace to investigate the select system call of a process and I'm trying to figure out what does `left` mean. Find below the debug line extracted from the strace log.

```
select(13, [6 7 8 11 12], [], NULL, {0, 10000}) = 1 (in [11], **left** {0, 9994})
```

So far, I didn't find anything in the available documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `select` updates the `timeout` parameter to indicate the amount of time that was left before the timeout.  This indicates that updated value, in usual `struct timeval` format (seconds and microseconds).  [See the strace source code to confirm this.](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/81e11a9b8c9469002833bd1707a435b1f81baf92/desc.c#L134)

So in this case, fd 11 became ready for reading when only 6 microseconds had elapsed.